# ASP Classic SQL Query does not work as intended

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am using ASP within HTML to create a website.
On one of my pages the SQL query `sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Details WHERE " &_
" Price BETWEEN '" & minPrice & "' AND '" & maxPrice & "' " &_
"OR Address_2 LIKE '" & searchFor & "'  "`
 is used to search a database and display the correct entries based on what was on a form. This works for the `Address_2` part of the query but the `BETWEEN` is not working correctly.
`minPrice` and `maxPrice` are all declared earlier and the correct form data is being taken as I have tested it with `<%= minPrice %>` what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `minPrice` and `maxPrice` are numbers, so you don't need apostrophe. Currently with your query you are getting SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Property_Details 
WHERE Price BETWEEN '10' AND '20'
```

Since 10 and 20 are numbers, so you should not use `'` around them. Try changing your query to the following:

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Details WHERE " &_
" Price BETWEEN " & minPrice & " AND " & maxPrice & " " &_
"OR Address_2 LIKE '" & searchFor & "'  "
```

Just as a side note - I don't know where `minPrice`, `maxPrice` and `searchFor` are coming from, but if they come from user input you could be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks, they are declared with `searchFor = Replace( Request.Form( "searchFor" ), "'", "''")
maxPrice =  Replace( Request.Form( "maxPrice" ), "'", "''")
minPrice =  Replace( Request.Form( "minPrice" ), "'", "''") `

quick question, will I need to convert these with CLng() if the database entry is long integer?

Comment: You need to pass raw numbers to `minPrice` and `maxPrice` in the query, so try converting the incoming values to numbers. And it seems you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, there are multiple sources on the web about how to fix that

Comment: The replace function was my attempt, I had first broken into my website with `' or ''='` and stopped that with this function

Comment: Do you have an example of how I pass raw numbers to `minPrice` and `MaxPrice`? I tried to convert them using `maxPrice = CLng( maxprice )` but that is not working